# c# How to iterate through the file system and assign numbering

Tags: c#, list, filesystems

I have a problem that is doing my head in.

I want to iterate through the local PC folders, including directories, and calculate a numbering system against each folder in the file system hierarchy.

The root folders should calculate as 1,2,3 etc.

If there were three sub-folders in folder one the calculated numbers should be:
1.1, 1.2,1.3

If there were three sub-folders in the sub-folder above then the calculated numbers should be:
1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3

If there were three sub-folders in folder two (a root folder) the calculated numbers should be:
2.1, 2.2, 2.3

Or expressed in another way:

```
 1   Root Folder 
 1.1   Root Sub Folder 1
 1.1.1   Sub Folder
 1.1.2     Sub Folder
 1.2 Root Sub Folder 2
 1.2.1 List item
 1.2.2   List item
```

etc. etc.

This logic should then be applied to all folders and sub-folders.

Output Example

```
1.1.1 | "c:\Root\Folder1\Folder1\"
```

What I have so far appears to work ok in some situations but can fail in other situations:

```
    private string rootpath = @"C:\FolderHierarchy\";
    private string FolderSequenceCountBase = "";
    private int CurrentRootPathCount = 0;
    private int Counter = 0;

    private void CalculateFolderHierarchyNumbers()
    {
        //Get First List of Folders
        string[] Dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(rootpath, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

        for (int i = 0; i < Dirs.Count(); i++)
        {
            FolderSequenceCountBase = (i + 1).ToString();
            CurrentRootPathCount = i + 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Processed folder '{0}'.", Dirs[i] + " = " + (i + 1));                
            GetSubDirs(Dirs[i]);
        }
    }

    private void GetSubDirs(string item)
    {
        //Get next list of folders in the folder hierarchy
        string[] SubDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(item, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        foreach (var DirPath in SubDirs)
        {
            //Increment count of folders within the current folder list
            Counter += 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Processed folder '{0}'.", DirPath + " = " + FolderSequenceCountBase + "." + Counter);
        }

        Counter = 0;

        //Get next list of folders in the folder hierarchy
        foreach (var DirPath in SubDirs)
        {
            FolderSequenceCountBase += ".1";
            GetSubDirs(DirPath);  
        }
    }
```

Hope this is clear.

Thanks
Rick

Comment: Do you mean you wish to extract the numbers present in each of the folders? You should also show any previous attempt you have made at solving the problem

Comment: Does the directory or file always ends with a number? What if it does not?

Comment: Am I understanding correctly you know how to traverese the directories,... but have troubles putting that numeration there? (it would be good if you also post the code you use for the traversion into your question). @TimSchmelter From how I understand it Folder1, Folder2,... are just mere examplenames and the number in the foldernames/filenames is only coincidence and has nothing to do with the numbering he wants to do

Comment: (but would be good if rick450d woiuld also clear that or post if that is the case or not and also what defines which number a specific folder/file gets [only order indside directory or something else)

Comment: Just add an additional STRING parameter to your "listfolder" and "listfiles" functions. --> done

Answer (score 0):

So you want to find a file and get it's the number of it in the of directory and all of it's parent directories? Since i found it interesting i've written something from scratch. Note that it's currently not tested but it might give you an idea anyway:

```
public static IEnumerable<FileEntryInfo> EnumerateFindFiles(string fileToFind, StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase, DirectoryInfo rootDir = null, string[] drivesToSearch = null)
{
    IEnumerable<FileEntryInfo> foundEntries = Enumerable.Empty<FileEntryInfo>();
    if (rootDir != null && drivesToSearch != null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Specify either the root-dir or the drives to search, not both");
    else if (rootDir != null)
    {
        foundEntries = EnumerateFindEntryRoot(fileToFind, rootDir, comparison);
    }
    else
    {
        if (drivesToSearch == null) // search the entire computer
            drivesToSearch = System.Environment.GetLogicalDrives();
        foreach (string dr in drivesToSearch)
        {
            System.IO.DriveInfo di = new System.IO.DriveInfo(dr);

            if (!di.IsReady)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The drive {0} could not be read", di.Name);
                continue;
            }
            rootDir = di.RootDirectory;
            foundEntries = foundEntries.Concat(EnumerateFindEntryRoot(fileToFind, rootDir, comparison));
        }
    }
    foreach (FileEntryInfo entry in foundEntries)
        yield return entry;
}

public class FileEntryInfo
{
    public FileEntryInfo(string path, int number)
    {
        this.Path = path;
        this.Number = number;
    }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public FileEntryInfo Root { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<int> GetNumberTree()
    {
        Stack<FileEntryInfo> filo = new Stack<FileEntryInfo>();
        FileEntryInfo entry = this;
        while (entry.Root != null)
        {
            filo.Push(entry.Root);
            entry = entry.Root;
        }
        while(filo.Count > 0)
            yield return filo.Pop().Number;
        yield return this.Number; 
    }


    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        FileEntryInfo fei = obj as FileEntryInfo;
        if(obj == null) return false;
        return Number == fei.Number && Path == fei.Path;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Path.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Path;
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<FileEntryInfo> EnumerateFindEntryRoot(string fileNameToFind, DirectoryInfo rootDir, StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
{
    Queue<FileEntryInfo> queue = new Queue<FileEntryInfo>();
    FileEntryInfo root = new FileEntryInfo(rootDir.FullName, 1);
    queue.Enqueue(root);

    while (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        FileEntryInfo fe = queue.Dequeue();
        List<FileEntryInfo> validFiles = new List<FileEntryInfo>();
        try
        { // you cannot yield from try-catch, hence this approach
            FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(fe.Path);
            //detect whether its a directory or file
            bool isDirectory = (attr & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory;
            if (isDirectory)
            {
                int entryCount = 0;
                foreach (string entry in Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(fe.Path))
                {
                    entryCount++;
                    FileEntryInfo subEntry = new FileEntryInfo(entry, entryCount);
                    subEntry.Root = fe;
                    queue.Enqueue(subEntry);
                    attr = File.GetAttributes(entry);
                    isDirectory = (attr & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory;
                    if(!isDirectory)
                        validFiles.Add(subEntry);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ex); // ignore, proceed
        }

        foreach (FileEntryInfo entry in validFiles)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(entry.Path);
            if (fileName.Equals(fileNameToFind, comparison))
                yield return entry;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how i tested it:

```
var allEntriesFound = EnumerateFindFiles("PresentationFramework.dll").ToList();
if(allEntriesFound.Any())
{
    foreach (FileEntryInfo entry in allEntriesFound)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: Number: {1}", entry.Path, entry.Number);
    // here your exact requirement:
    string result = string.Join(".", allEntriesFound[0].GetNumberTree());
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Added also a way to specify the root directory to prevent that the whole file system is searched, Usage:

```
var allEntriesFound = EnumerateFindFiles(
  "PresentationFramework.dll", 
  StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase,
  new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Windows"))
.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Tim but I do not want to find a specific file just assign a number to the folder hierarchy which I will then write to a file. I will also extend this to files once the directory numbering calculation is solved.